# Getting and Setting SQL Timeout?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, timeout

When running a linq query, I get the following error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not
>   responding.

I'm curious to know how I can view and modify this value to see if this just needs to be bigger or if there's something wrong with my query.  My query has worked in the past, so I would like to think some timeout setting was changed since it was last working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a Linq2Sql `DataContext`, it's available at `YourDataContext.CommandTimeout`.

For a `SqlConnection`, the `CommandTimeout` is a property of the `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: I see: YourDataContext.Connection.ConnectionTimeout.  Is this in seconds, or milliseconds?

Comment: @sooprise: `ConnectionTimeout` is only used when connecting to the database.  For running queries, the `CommandTimeout` is used (edited in answer :))

Comment: Also, this value seems to be read only, how can I set this value?